# Optimize the kernel function based on parellel reduction

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

In one of my previous posts I asked how it was possible to improve a kernel function. The kernel compute the squared euclidean distance between the corresponding rows of two equal sized matrices. **Eric** gave a very good tip to use one thread block per row and after that apply parallel reduction. Before continue with further details this post is made because I did not want to make more complicated the previous post and I give my thanks to **Eric**. Below I attached the .cu code which is not give me the correct results.

```
__global__ void cudaEuclid( float* A, float* B, float* C, int rows, int cols )
{
    extern __shared__ float sdata[];

    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int c = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x; // rows
    unsigned int r = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y; // cols


    sdata[ tid ] = ( A[ r*cols + c ] - B[ r*cols + c ] ) * ( A[ r*cols + c ] - B[ r*cols + c ] );

    __syncthreads();

    for ( unsigned int s = 1; s < blockDim.x; s*=2 ){
        if ( tid % (2*s) == 0 ){
            sdata[ tid ] += sdata[ tid + s ];
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();

    if ( tid == 0) C[blockIdx.x]=sdata[0];  
}
```

The code is based on the http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf. It is not the optimized version. I am just want to catch the basic point. I think that there is a problem where I initialize the `sdata`. Also the initialization of the kernel is done by this way:

```
int threadsPerBlock = 256;  
int blocksPerGrid = ceil( (double) numElements  / threadsPerBlock);

dim3 dimBlock(1, threadsPerBlock); 
dim3 dimGrid(blocksPerGrid, 1); 

cudaEuclid<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>( d_A, d_B, d_C, rows, cols );
```

Thank you and sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using dynamically allocated shared memory, yet you're not actually allocating any shared memory. The kernel launch should have an additional parameter for the size of shared memory per block.

```
cudaEuclid<<<dimGrid, dimBlock, threadsPerBlock*sizeof(float)>>>( d_A, d_B, d_C, rows, cols );
```

- Consider using [CUB](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/) for reduction - saves you from reimplementing from scratch and is tuned.
- If you want to code it yourself, there's a [more recent version](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction) of the example than the version from CUDA 1.1-beta!

Comment: Thanks for the correction and the link. The part of the code `sdata[ tid ] = ( A[ r*cols + c ] - B[ r*cols + c ] ) * ( A[ r*cols + c ] - B[ r*cols + c ] );` do you found it correct? I have a lot of doubts. Also is the kernel initialization correct? Any suggestions on that? Sorry for this kind of questions but a very beginner.

Comment: I would use CUB for the reduction, so assign the thread-local result to a variable then just call cub::reduce (compute the difference once then square it, compiler should be fine but makes it more readable). Your grid config looks odd, you have a width of 1 and a height of 256 which will lead to uncoalesced (poor perf) accesses. I'd have expected to see a tile e.g. 32x4.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about CUB but I prefer to do it on my own. Is is not a game of optimum performance for the scope of a project but I am looking in the low level-academic understanding. Thanks again.

Comment: Reduction is a great learning example if you take it from naive to advanced, but for any real code I would always encourage reuse of libraries where possible. You should also look at the Scan examples, good to see how an apparently serial algorithm can map to a parallel architecture.

Answer (score 0):

sdata[ tid ] += sdata[ tid ]; ==> you are just adding the same value twice 
you need to do

sdata[tid] += sdata[tid +s ]